# Hibernate Bandwidth Issue: Taking a lot more time than SQL Developer

Tags: hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am experiencing a strange issued with Hibernate. I am running a simple query that return around 300.000 results

select COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D, COLUMN_E, COLUMN_F 
from MY_TABLE 
where COLUMN_G = 'Reporting';

In SQL developer is taking around 1 minute. But in Hibernate is taking 4 minutes.

```
    String queryString = "select COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D, COLUMN_E, COLUMN_F from MY_TABLE where COLUMN_G = 'Reporting'";
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString, Reporting.class);
    List<ReportingScore> result = query.getResultList();
```

I don't think the overhead of Hibernate creating the objects is the cause of the issue.

I noticed by looking to the Windows task manager when SQL Developer is executing the query, the bandwidth is in average 1.1Mbps

But when Hibernate is executing the very same query it is receiving the response at a pace of 300Kbps (1/3 slower).

[image]

Does anyone knows why hibernate data transfer is slower than in this case slower that SQL Developer?
Is there anyway to configure how hibernate control the bandwidth? (i never heard anything about it)

My application is a spring-boot application with version 2.1.1.RELEASE.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing exactly same issue with Hibernate slowness when compiling the application as jars in jar and then running with JRE8. Solution was to have hibernate libraries with expanded classes within the final jar (or dependency jars aside in lib directory)

Starting from JRE8 the jars in jar is adding extreme slowness into hibernate query executions.

EDIT: In my case it was not the spring boot issue or hibernate issue, but how the JRE8 handles the zip deflating, after compiling by maven with following plugin setting the performance significantly improved

```
...
        <build>

           <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <mainClass>myapp.mainclass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
              </plugin> 
...
           </plugins>
        </build>
...
```

Comment: I wonder if is a spring boot issue or the way spring-boot bundles the jars?

Comment: Please see my EDIT above, can you confirm how are you compiling the code?

Comment: Thank you very much. I think i understand what you mean. This is creating a jar-with-dependencies exploded inside which may increase the process speed. But in my case, i am using a war file and dropping it into a tomcat server. Perhaps i mislead by saying this is a spring boot application. It is in fact, except when is dropped into production/staging or dev servers) Locally we run the application as spring-boot for the sake of simplicity